# Saving output from terminal in txt file and also prints output in terminal

Tags: python

How can I save output from terminal in txt file and also prints output in terminal in the same time?

I tried with `python3 script_name > output.txt` but this save the output in txt file but nothing happens in terminal. I also have `plt.show()` and when script ends then it need to show output image, but says the error:

```
UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /tmp/pip-req-build-19kunu9c/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
/home/pytorch_ArT.py:141: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

I have tkinter installed version 8.6.

Comment: if you are using bash, try `python script_name > output.txt &&  cat output.txt`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Then you should have access to [`tee`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee), which you might use following way

```
python3 script_name | tee output.txt
```